# get value of checkbox laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I want to return an array that contains my list checked I do this :
**View :**

```
 {{ Form::checkbox('saison[]', $saison->id, false,array('class' =>'chk')) }} 
 {{ HTML::link('ouvrircompte', 'Valider') }}
```

**Controller :**

```
 public function postOuvrircompte() {

    $saisons =Input::get('saison');
    foreach ($saisons as $saison)
       echo $saison ;
    // ....
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('biens/{id}/details', 'UserController@postOuvrircompte');
```

But I have no result

Comment: Can you show the complete form (or at least the form opening)? Also i don't see any relation between your form and your method.

Comment: You're right I have deleted the form :p but when i have added it that's work thanks :)